# Configuring multiple interfaces with a gateway each

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, sip

I am trying to configure a SIP networking interface. My goal is to **siproxd** my internet-interface (`enp3s0`) to the SIP ethernet device (`enp4s0`). I have edited my `/etc/network/interfaces` like so:

```
root@debian:/home/debian# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
              address xxx.xx.xx.xx (removed, but this is working just fine - I wouldn't beable to connect wth SSH without this)
              gateway xxx.xx.xx.x
              netmask 255.255.255.0

auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet static
              address 10.50.146.130
              gateway 10.50.146.129
              netmask 255.255.255.252

dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

However, when I attempt to ping my gateway `10.50.146.129`, I face failure. Things I have tried:

- Creating a new IP Route table and adding a `default` to it, then creating an IP Rule to pick that route
- Adding routes in various combinations of `via` as found online
- An `ip a` shows the `enp4s0` interface as up, along with the right IP next to it

At this point, I'd just like a pointer as to the right direction for doing this, as opposed to trial and error. How would you manage 2 network interfaces, both with a different gateway? It is crucial for me to accept incoming network traffic and proxy it into my SIP device - using `siproxd`.

Comment: If you're failing to ping 10.50.146.129, which is connected subnet, routing will not help you. Is enp4s0 up to begin with? Can you see arp reply from 10.50.146.129 using `ip neigh` command?

Comment: @ar_ I see `10.50.146.129 dev enp4s0  FAILED` - but `ip a` shows it as `3: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000`

Comment: Well, as long as arp is failed, I assume, you're having L2 reachability issues. Apparently ping is failing because of L2 switching failure as opposed to L3 routing one.

Comment: @ar_ Yikes! So its a connection issue - is my best bet engaging the hosting provider support? Thanks for a quick response btw :)

Comment: Well, it depends on your environment, but this is good idea to check connections along with ip configuration on other host somehow.